# How can I remove brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation

After some manipulations I have next result

```
k1={{0.00044646, {0.000012475}}, {0.151322, {-0.507718}}, {0.302266, 
{0.0156497}}, {0.453972, {-0.523798}}, {0.60577, {0.0321833}}, 
{0.758426, {-0.540792}}, {0.911204, {0.0496484}}, {1.06495, 
{-0.558735}}, {1.21885, {0.068077}}, {1.37385, {-0.577655}}, 
{1.52905, {0.0874981}}, {1.68548, {-0.597582}}, {1.84217, 
{0.107938}}, {2.00028, {-0.618537}}, {2.15868, {0.129415}}, {2.31872, 
{-0.640537}}, {2.47912, {0.151942}}, {2.64139, {-0.663588}}, 
{2.80411, {0.175522}}, {2.96901, {-0.68769}}, {3.13443, {0.200147}}, 
{3.3024, {-0.712828}}, {3.47101, {0.225795}}, {3.64261, {-0.738972}}, 
{3.81497, {0.25243}}, {3.99091, {-0.766076}}, {4.16775, {0.279994}}, 
{4.34892, {-0.794072}}, {4.53115, {0.308408}}, {4.71874, 
{-0.822867}}, {4.90756, {0.337565}}}
```

But I need it in the next form

```
k2={{0.15132244378079754, -0.5077175653829329}, {0.3022661890056194,0.015649728006162454}, {0.453971622486539,-0.5237979650152957}, 
{0.605770298409663, 0.03218327886853413}, {0.7584256500955757,-0.5407924834045306}, 
{0.9112041270341528, 0.049648363325219116}, {1.0649491075114248,-0.5587345226581542}, 
{1.2188521723915644,0.06807697730413116}, {1.3738493844916557,-0.5776554217041664}, 
{1.5290454926273367,0.08749808625530087}, {1.6854849642061058,-0.5975820947916276}, 
{1.8421709047147221,0.10793786646447988}, {2.0002758141403834,-0.6185372265069519}, 
{2.1586825822104965, 0.12941496174355907}, {2.3187165766176143,-0.6405366970664644}, 
{2.4791168853897236,0.15194172988973628}, {2.641393624309572, -0.6635884503138026}, 
{2.8041116740003837,0.17552177571940925}, {2.9690075398442675, -0.6876902914868068}, 
{3.1344320129682606,0.20014666168035775}, {3.302403421990638, -0.7128280785915296}, 
{3.471005177293706,0.22579533975608276}, {3.642612958523754, -0.7389724039942989}, 
{3.814969883166606,0.2524300488611815}, {3.990914723914559, -0.7660763576193386}, 
{4.167747826128888,0.27999366566582834}, {4.348924263022437, -0.7940719530990836}, 
{4.531152583846591,0.3084079059821292}, {4.718735846826107, -0.8228665080092031}, 
{4.907564692603037, 0.3375652965868383}};
```

Because I want to plot graph `ListPlot[k1]` and if I remove extra brackets like in `k2` I can plot the graph.

Comment: I'd use `Map`: `Map[Flatten, k1]` or with a shorthand notation: `Flatten /@ k1`.

Comment: It works.Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done with a data destructuring function.

```
data = 
  {{0.00044646, {0.000012475}}, {0.151322, {-0.507718}}, 
   {0.302266, {0.0156497}}, {0.453972, {-0.523798}}};

munge[{x_, {y_}}] := {x, y}

munge /@ data
```

> ```
> {{0.00044646, 0.000012475}, {0.151322, -0.507718}, 
>  {0.302266, 0.0156497}, {0.453972, -0.523798}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ArrayReshape`:

```
k2=ArrayReshape[k1, {Length[k1], 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for your specific problem is to combine `Flatten` and `Partition`.

`Flatten` applied at level 2 can produce a single list of all of the numbers:

```
Flatten[k1, 2]

(* {0.00044646, 0.000012475, 0.151322, -0.507718, 0.302266, \
0.0156497, 0.453972, -0.523798, 0.60577, 0.0321833, 0.758426, \
-0.540792, 0.911204, 0.0496484, 1.06495, -0.558735, 1.21885, \
0.068077, 1.37385, -0.577655, 1.52905, 0.0874981, 1.68548, -0.597582, \
1.84217, 0.107938, 2.00028, -0.618537, 2.15868, 0.129415, 2.31872, \
-0.640537, 2.47912, 0.151942, 2.64139, -0.663588, 2.80411, 0.175522, \
2.96901, -0.68769, 3.13443, 0.200147, 3.3024, -0.712828, 3.47101, \
0.225795, 3.64261, -0.738972, 3.81497, 0.25243, 3.99091, -0.766076, \
4.16775, 0.279994, 4.34892, -0.794072, 4.53115, 0.308408, 4.71874, \
-0.822867, 4.90756, 0.337565} *)
```

`Partition` with a second argument of 2 produces a nested list with two elements grouped together:

```
Partition[Flatten[k1, 2], 2]

(* {{0.00044646, 0.000012475}, {0.151322, -0.507718}, {0.302266,
   0.0156497}, {0.453972, -0.523798}, {0.60577, 
  0.0321833}, {0.758426, -0.540792}, {0.911204, 
  0.0496484}, {1.06495, -0.558735}, {1.21885, 
  0.068077}, {1.37385, -0.577655}, {1.52905, 
  0.0874981}, {1.68548, -0.597582}, {1.84217, 
  0.107938}, {2.00028, -0.618537}, {2.15868, 
  0.129415}, {2.31872, -0.640537}, {2.47912, 
  0.151942}, {2.64139, -0.663588}, {2.80411, 
  0.175522}, {2.96901, -0.68769}, {3.13443, 
  0.200147}, {3.3024, -0.712828}, {3.47101, 
  0.225795}, {3.64261, -0.738972}, {3.81497, 
  0.25243}, {3.99091, -0.766076}, {4.16775, 
  0.279994}, {4.34892, -0.794072}, {4.53115, 
  0.308408}, {4.71874, -0.822867}, {4.90756, 0.337565}} *)
```